# What is Best case in RelationshipEntity on Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to model some data using Neo4j.

In my case, a User writes comment on an Article. Which is a better way to represent this?

First: `User -[:COMMENT_ON] -> Article`

`COMMENT_ON` is a RelationshipEntity which includes comment contents and the date when it was written.

Second: `User - [:WRITE]-> Comment -[:BELONG_TO] -> Article`

This is a little complex but doesn't use RelationshipEntity.

Which is the better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always **it depends** ...

And in this case it depends on what you intend to do with the comments. Are they themselves an entrypoint into your graph ? Do you intend to search on the content ? Do you intend to find all the comments in a specific timeframe ? If so it definitely makes sense to have the comments as nodes.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom